# Selecting items across multiple slicers vba

Tags: excel, vba, slicers

I am working in an excel workbook that contains 5 pivot tables w/ a slicer connected to each that filters stats based on a market region.

I am trying to write a VBA program that connects the SLICERS together. For instance if I select a region on Slicer1 I want that region to be selected on the other 4.

[If Auro is selected in the first slicer, it should be selected in the others and no other region should be selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9QPL.png)

Here is the code I have written:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)
Dim sc1 As SlicerCache
Dim sc2 As SlicerCache
Dim sc3 As SlicerCache
Dim sc4 As SlicerCache
Dim sc5 As SlicerCache
Dim SI1 As SlicerItem

'These names come from Slicer Settings dialog box
Set sc1 = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Market")
Set sc2 = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Market1")
Set sc3 = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Market2")
Set sc4 = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Market3")
Set sc5 = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Market4")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

sc2.ClearManualFilter
sc3.ClearManualFilter
sc4.ClearManualFilter
sc5.ClearManualFilter

For Each SI1 In sc1.SlicerItems
    sc2.SlicerItems(SI1.Name).Selected = SI1.Selected
    sc3.SlicerItems(SI1.Name).Selected = SI1.Selected
    sc4.SlicerItems(SI1.Name).Selected = SI1.Selected
    sc5.SlicerItems(SI1.Name).Selected = SI1.Selected

Next SI1

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I'm getting a run-time error '5' on the first line after the FOR EACH LOOP.

Comment: In the image you provided, the 2nd and 4th slicers do not include "AURO" - so how do you want to handle that scenario, since one of the slicer options always has to be selected? I.e. "no other region should be selected" is impossible in that case.

Comment: Hmmm...I see what you are saying. I am going to see if I am able to add the same slicer options for every slicer, regardless if there is data for that option.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for pointing that out. A very simple fix.